# Why appendChild works asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

In the following code, `div.appendChild(img)` is not inside `reader.onload` function which is an asynchronous handler i.e. runs only when reading file data is complete. That means `div.appendChild(img)` which is outside & below the `reader.onload` event should've run before the `reader.onload` event is complete and thus should show nothing per se.

However, When the the handler for the onload event is complete i.e. files is read, then `div.appendChild(img)` fires which means appendChild(img) runs asynchronously. Is this the correct behavior. Please correct if not.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput">   

<div id="demoDiv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
let control = document.getElementById('fileInput') 
let div = document.getElementById('demoDiv') 

control.addEventListener('change', handleFiles)


function handleFiles() {
  let img = document.createElement('img')
  let file = this.files[0]

  let reader = new FileReader(file)
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  reader.onload = function() {
    img.src = this.result
  }

  div.appendChild(img)
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a matter of being synchronous or not, what happens is that `img` is a pointer to an HTML element, as specified in `let img = document.createElement('img')`.

When you do this:

```
div.appendChild(img)
```

You are appending an element to your `div`. It doesn't matter when exactly that happens, since you hold the reference to that element. Then, when you do this:

```
img.src = this.result
```

You mutate the element which you created. Therefore, regardless of the order in which the operations happen, they will execute correctly.

If `div.appendChild(img)` happens first, the `src` will be mutated when the files are read and the image will appear. If not, the `src` will already be present when the `img` is appended, and you end with same result.